# Resource groups are not shown in response while using Azure Rest APIs

Tags: azure, api, permissions

I am accessing azure server information using following URL

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub id>/resourceGroups/?api-version=2018-02-01

But the response of this api is an empty array. Although, a resource group is already there in web portal. Is there some permission issue as my user is already added as owner for Azure AD user, group or service principal.

Comment: How are you attempting to get this information?  Are you using Postman, cURL or some other method.  How are you authenticating this REST call?

Comment: @KenWMSFT I am RestSharp to call this URL. For authentication I have created active directory and then generating token from using https://login.microsoftonline.com/<sub id>/oauth2/token

Answer (score 0):

this is the proper url to call:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2019-05-10
```

notice there is no `/` after `resourcegroups`.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/list

Comment: Response is same, empty collection

Comment: you probably do not have proper permissions. fix that

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that fix as well and found out that **Azure Management Resource** needs to be added in access control IAM under the subscription or resource group. But it turns out that there is no such permission there in azure portal when I tried to add it for the specific role.

Comment: no, your account needs Microsoft.resources/resourcegroups/read permissions. something along those lines